# Change app web path in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I need to change the configuration of app path in symfony which I'm not able to find.

Company has changed the domain name & it still points to old domain for CSS, JS & everything else.

In layout.php file,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo sfconfig::get('app_web_path'); ?>
js/ip.js"></script>
```

This `app_web_path` parameter is taking value from some file which I'm not able to find. Can somebody help where this is coming from?

I changed `app.yml` & mentioned new domains there, but no luck. TIA.

Comment: sfconfig is from Symfony 1.  Might get more help if you adjusted your tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a custom setting created in one of the app.yml files.

In Symfony 1.*, the config parameters map to any one of the .yml files.  For `'app_web_path'`, you want to look in one of the app.yml files (which sounds like you did already).  Then you want to look for an entry like:

```
all:
  web:
    path: example.com
```

After changing the setting, you need to the clear the Symfony cache, otherwise the change will have no effect.

For more info on how app.yml works, read http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/11-app and for more info on Symfony 1.x configuration read  http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/19-Mastering-Symfony-s-Configuration-Files

Answer (score 0):

A better way to insert that JS is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo public_path('js/ip.js') ?>"></script>
```